# Banach contraction mapping

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In my note, i'm studying about metric space. In this section I also study about Banach contraction mapping theorem. Can i use Banach contraction mapping to find a solution for question below ? anyone can help me. Thank you

> How to find a solution of the equation $f(x) = x$ for $x = (x_1, x_2,x_3) \in \mathbb E^3$ (euclidean space) , where $f(x_1, x_2,x_3)=(\frac {x_1}{5} +\frac {x_2}{2}+\frac {x_3}{4}-1,\frac {x_1}{3} +\frac {x_2}{3}+\frac {x_3}{4}+2, \frac {x_1}{4} +\frac {x_2}{15}+\frac {x_3}{4}+3) $

Comment: Yea you can, remember that in the proof of the contraction principle the existence of a fixed point is shown by repeated iterations of the function. Such a procedure will lead you then to the fixed point you are looking for.

Comment: can you show me how to do it, because in general i study to find a solution using banach contraction only for simple equality. for example solve equation $x^3-4x+1=0$. But this question, it uses three $x_1, x_2, x_3$

Comment: It is possible to use the contraction mapping principle, but you could also note that $f(x)=Ax+b$ where $A$ is a $3$-by-$3$ matrix and $b$ is a constant vector, so $Ax+b=x$ has unique solution $x=(A-I)^{-1}b$ if $A-I$ is invertible (which it is).  (You could also note that $f(x)-f(y)=A(x-y)$, so to show it is a contraction you want to show that $\|A(x-y)\|\leq c\|x-y\|$ for some $c<1$.  Using the Euclidean norm, the largest $c$ is the square root of the largest eigenvalue of $A^TA$, which is a little less than $0.84$.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  You should review the contraction mapping theorem.  It says that if you are trying to solve $f(x)=x$ and $|f'(x)| \lt q \lt 1$ in the region of interest you can just iterate $x_{i+1}=f(x_i)$ to find a solution.  The derivative condition says that the distance from the solution is multiplied by a factor of (about) $q$ each time and since $q \lt 1, q^n \to 0$.  You need to verify that the eigenvalues of the matrix $\frac {\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ are all less than $1$.  The maximum eigenvalue becomes your $q$ in the theorem.

Comment: the same comment i give to you, can you show me how to do it, because in general i study to find a solution using banach contraction only for simple equality. for example solve equation $x3−4x+1=0$
. But this question, it uses three$ x_1,x_2,x_3$

Comment: The matrix of partials I mentioned has one direction for the components of $f$ and the other direction for the variable to take the partial with respect to.  You should be able to read off the entries in the matrix from the definition of $f$.  What is $\frac {\partial f_3}{\partial x_2}$?  It is $\frac 1{15}$.  Do you see it?

Comment: yes, i see. and what is the meaning of maximum eigenvalue ?

Comment: The matrix will have three eigenvalues.  Do you know what those are?  If the matrix is $A$ the eigenvalue equation is $Ax=\lambda x$ so the eigenvectors are ones that don't have their directions changed on multiplication by $A$.  The eigenvalues are the $\lambda$s.  There are typically as many as the size of $A$.  If you are not familiar with this, you need a different approach than I have in my toolbox.

Comment: Having eigenvalues all less than $1$ doesn't imply it is a contraction (depending on the norm used), but having spectral radius less than $1$ does imply that there is a power of the matrix that is a contraction, which would be enough to apply a generalized version of the fixed point theorem.   E.g., a strictly upper triangular matrix with large entries above the diagonal has only eigenvalues $0$, but is not a contraction.